# InstaPy bot follow someone's follower problem

Tags: python, selenium, instapy

I am trying to use instapy bot for automation following follower of someone's instagram per below code. It runs smoothly to login and click into someone profile but cannot find follower link as below feedback. Also 0 follower followed. What is the root cause?

**Could not find followers' link for 'someone'**

**Grabbed 0 usernames from 'someone's `Followers` to do following**

**Finished following 1 users' `Followers`! xD**

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

insta_username = ''
insta_password = ''
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username, password=insta_password, headless_browser=False)
session.login()

with smart_run(session):
  session.follow_user_followers(['someone'], amount=10, randomize=False, sleep_delay=20)
```